# How the process “ lock a certain amount of coins into the network as their stake” achieved technically in the Proof of stake algorithm

Tags: blockchain, network, proof-of-stake, forging

i am trying to understand deeper the proof of stake algorithm. i think i understand the basics but i am struggling to understand how this achieved thoroughly under blockchain network and how the nodes interact. So to get started, when a node wants to participate in the forging or minted process are required to lock a certain amount of coins into the network as their stake. The size of the stake determines the chances for a node to be selected as the next validator to forge the next block. My main question now is how this can be achieved technically.
Does every node have Deposit storage for the staked money?
Does every node propagate the staked money to the other nodes?

Let's Assume, that there are ***N*** nodes that stake money and ***i*** is the node that is selected to propose block. How this node ***i*** became known to the others ***(N-1)*** nodes (if it is possible  just don't answer me through a leader election process but how can this achieved what are the steps to figure it out).